# bluetoooth qualification and certification for proprietary custom gatt services

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed some proprietary custom BLE GATT services on top of bluez-5.43 stack.

My question is how do i now qualify my services to get my product certified as bluetooth smart by SIG.

Can anyone mention the steps I need to follow,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to qualify your custom service if it has a 128-bit UUID. You however need to pay the Declaration Fee for the physical product itself, per the listing at https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/qualification-listing-fees.